# Python - Ordering a dictionary with the array from file

Tags: python

I have been trying to fetch the last and first field from the **/etc/passwd** file in Linux. I want to fetch the last fields of the file(**the shell which users are using**) and the first field(**number of users using the shell**) and add it to a list. For eg my final output must be something like

```
 {"/bin/bash/" :[username1,username2],"/usr/sbin/nologin": [username2]}
```

Basically, I want the key of the dictionary to be the shell and its value must be an array of users.

For this, I have tried the below code

```
password_file = '/etc/passwd'
handler = open(password_file)
empty_dict = {}

for line in handler:
    last_line = line.split(':')[6]       #to fetch last line
    first_line = line.split(':')[0]           #to fetch first line
    userlist[]                               #create an array for users
    userlist.append(first_line)
    if(first_line not in last_line):
      empty_dict[last_line] = userlist     #adding the user array to the dict as value
      print(empty_dict)
```

This gives the output but this doesn't involve all the users to the dictionary key. Can you guys help me on which logic I went wrong? Any help would be great. Thank you

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean by "This gives the output but this doesn't involve all the users to the dictionary key", can you maybe give us some more info or the exact output you're looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you're resetting the `userlist` inside the loop. Here is one possible way of doing this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

password_file = '/etc/passwd'
handler = open(password_file)

userlist = defaultdict(list)
for line in handler:
    first, *_, last = line.strip().split(':')
    if first not in last:
      userlist[last or 'nologin'].append(first)

handler.close()
```

Comment: perfect, this one does the job..thank you